# Can't detect whether a shell function is defined from a script

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

I have a bash script that is supposed to check if the user has a function defined, then if there is not function that exists, will define the function in their `~/.bashrc` file. I've simplified the code for display purposes. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

brc="$HOME/.bashrc"

exists=false

# check if the function exists
if [ -n "$(type -t cs)" ] && [ "$(type -t cs)" = function ]; then 
    exists=true 
fi

if [ "$exists" = false ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Through a lot of `echo` tests, I've figured out that regardless of whether the function called `cs` exists for me, the first conditional statement always evaluates to `false`. The strange thing is that, when I copy and paste those lines into my shell directly without running a script, the line evaluates to `true`! Please help.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` is your friend here.

Comment: ...that said, functions aren't inherited from the parent process unless you exported them, so when you run a script, it has no way of knowing which functions are or aren't defined in your interactive shell.

Comment: But then OP defined the function in `.bashrc`, and it should be available for the script upon _sourcing_ it right?

Comment: @Inian, sure -- *if* they modified their script to source that file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thought that the _source_ being done was explicit, it seems now, it has not been done

Comment: @CodyPatterson, ...btw, there's no need for the separate `-n` -- you're quoting correctly, so `[ "$(type -t cs)" = function ]` is entirely safe on its own.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your comments and your answer it was very helpful, informative, and solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they've been exported with `export -f`, functions are *local to a single instance of the shell*. Your script runs in a different instance.

If you want your command to be able to determine which shell functions are active, you should either write it to be sourced into an existing shell rather than executed as an external command, or define it as a shell function itself.

You could also source in `.bashrc`, if you're willing to deal with your script's behavior being modified by its side effects:

```
brc="$HOME/.bashrc"
[[ -e "$brc" ]] && source "$brc"
```

Comment: Are there any issues with adding `export -f cs` to my `.bashrc` file after defining the function in there? Any build-up of repeated definitions of `cs` in the environment?

Comment: Nope -- one environment variable per function, so you're safe in that respect. The only real gotcha with exported functions is that due to shellshock, the format has changed, so if you use different versions of bash (as is fairly common on OS X since its stock one is so ancient), a function exported by one may not be recognized by the other.

Answer (score 1):

By default `.bashrc` will not be loaded for non-interactive shells, for example this is from my (default) `.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Or you might have something like:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

So you need to either figure out how to load the `.bashrc` in a non-interactive shell (depends on the way it's checked in your system) or source the function from another file.